# Chef application_java cookbook - uninitialized constant Chef::DSL

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a problem with application_java cookbook. I added recipe into application_java cookbook to deploy my .war archive to Tomcat. This is how it looks like:

```
case node['platform']
when 'debian', 'ubuntu'
  include_recipe 'apt'
end
include_recipe 'java' # Need described below

application 'ensembleAPI' do
  path         "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ensembleRestApi.war"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0777"
  repository   'ensembleRestApi.war'
scm_provider Chef::Provider::File::Deploy

java_webapp
tomcat
end
```

I think this is OK. But when I run all process with **vagrant up** it ends with following error

```
NameError
---------
uninitialized constant Chef::DSL
Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/application_java/providers/java_webapp.rb:20:in `class_from_file'
```

My chef version is 11.10.2.

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Chef 11+. The error:

```
NameError
---------
uninitialized constant Chef::DSL
```

Comes from this [line in the cookbook](https://github.com/poise/application_java/blob/master/providers/java_webapp.rb#L20)...

```
include Chef::DSL::IncludeRecipe
```

The `Chef::DSL` class doesn't exist in earlier versions of Chef. If you're using Vagrant, it sounds like you may be using a Vagrant box that has Chef preinstalled at an older version. I suggest looking into Chef's "[Bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento)" project, which has newer base boxes without Chef installed, that you can use with the "[vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus)" plugin to get the version of Chef you want to use via Chef's omnibus packages.